# Add film grain, resize and create SBS file for stereo 3D

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 files at 1080p resolution.

I wish to resize each to 1920x2160, combine both into SBS 3840x2160, add subtle film grain, add burn subtitles into each eye and finally create an SBS 4K stereo 3D video file with CRF 18.

I have used ffmpeg previously but this is way beyond my understanding for the filters.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I ended up with the following

```
ffmpeg -i L.mov -i R.mov -i Audio.wav  -filter_complex "[0]subtitles=subs.srt,scale=3840x1080:flags=lanczos,setsar=1[l];[1]subtitles=subs.srt,scale=3840x1080:flags=lanczos,setsar=1[r];[l][r]vstack" -crf 18 -c:v libx265 -pix_fmt yuv422p -map 2:a -c:a aac -b:a 320k -metadata:s:v stereo_mode=left_right movie_3dpv.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

By 1080p, I assume you mean 1920x1080. Use

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex
   "[0]noise,subtitles=subs.srt,scale=1920x2160,setsar=1[l];
    [1]noise,subtitles=subs.srt,scale=1920x2160,setsar=1[r];
    [l][r]hstack" -crf 18 -c:a copy -metadata:s:v stereo_mode=left_right out.mkv
```

See the docs for the [noise](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#noise) filter to alter its default values.